# Disable width inherit?

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm working on developing a basic Android app for school and am having some issues with the layout. I am using a table layout with several rows.

The problem I'm having is with the width of items. When I add buttons to the top or bottom of the page, the text views in the other rows seem to inherit the button width. I need these text views to be narrow, about the size of a single character. It seems that the items width is set to the widest item in the table. I've tried several properties but have had no luck.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Here's a screenshot -

[image: As you can see, the textViews are inheriting the width of the start button]

Here's my code -

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="fill"
android:padding="20dp"
android:shrinkColumns="1" >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
        android:text=""         
        android:height="50dp"
        android:width="50dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:width="50dp"
        android:height="50dp" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:width="50dp"
        android:height="50dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:width="50dp"
        android:height="50dp" />

</TableRow>
```

Comment: Hello Joshua, it would be helpful if you could post your layout for others to see.

Comment: @MichaelKrause Just added code snippet. Should I add screenshot aswell?

Comment: @JerichoDefeated a screenshot would be VERY helpful

Comment: @AlexK Just added a screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `layout_span` to your views according to how many columns you want the particular view to span.

For example, in your code:

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start"
        android:layout_span="2" />

</TableRow>
```

Then for each `TextView` give a `layout_span` of 1.